# My text is auto-breaking when i didn't even add <br> tag

Tags: php, html

I coded notifications in php, it works but it comes out looking like this...

[image]

I didn't add `br` tag so why is the TEXT breaking?

Here's the line of code...

```
echo "<div class='entire' style='width:100%;height:200px;'><div class=" . $row["not_type"]. "  style='height:50px;width:50px';>" . $row["from_user_id"]. "  " . $row["from_username"]. " " . $row["not_text"]. "      " . $row["post_id"]. "" . $row["post_content_url"]. " " . $row["post_id"]. "<br>";
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: you're not closing your `div` tags in your echo

Comment: What is not specific about this @PedroLobito?

Answer (score 1):

By default text will wrap to fit the container. If you don't want text to wrap set `white-space: nowrap`. If you then get a scrollbar you can add `overflow: hidden`.

Your container is only `50px` wide.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `</div>` at the of the echo.

Try this:

```
echo "<div class='entire' style='width:100%;height:200px;'><div class=" . $row["not_type"]. "  style='height:50px;width:50px';>" . $row["from_user_id"]. "  " . $row["from_username"]. " " . $row["not_text"]. "      " . $row["post_id"]. "" . $row["post_content_url"]. " " . $row["post_id"]. "</div><br>";
```